# Using Rust X11 bindings to move a window

Tags: rust, x11

I'm trying to move a window (the GNOME terminal) with [x11rb](https://github.com/psychon/x11rb). I followed [this](https://github.com/psychon/x11rb/blob/15153e514a4e3e4c116279f76ab1c3635abc05e5/x11rb/examples/tutorial.rs) tutorial. But the `move_window` function doesn't move the window.

```
use x11rb::connection::Connection;
use x11rb::protocol::xproto::*;
use x11rb::rust_connection::ReplyError;

fn move_window<C: Connection>(conn: &C, win: Window) -> Result<(), ReplyError> {    
    // Changing the size doesn't work either
    // let values = ConfigureWindowAux::default().width(100).height(100);
    let values = ConfigureWindowAux::default().x(100).y(100);

    println!("values: {:?}", values);
    conn.configure_window(win, &values)?;

    Ok(())
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let (conn, screen_num) = x11rb::connect(None)?;
    let screen = &conn.setup().roots[screen_num];

    // `move_window` doesn't reposition the window even if I hardcode the id.
    // I also tried 0x4000006. It doesn't work either.
    // let win_id = 67108871;

    // Get the root window ID
    let root_win = screen.root;

    println!("root_win: {}", root_win);

    // Query the X11 server for the window ID of the active window
    let active_win = conn.get_input_focus()?.reply()?.focus;

    println!("active_win: {}", active_win);

    // Move the active window to position (100, 100)
    move_window(&conn, active_win)?;

    Ok(())
}
```

I made sure it's the right window:

```
xwininfo: Window id: 0x4000006 "alex@alex-M52AD-M12AD-A-F-K31AD: ~/rust/x11rb-tutorial"
```

And all the values seem correct:

```
root_win: 661
active_win: 67108871 // 67108871 equals to 0x4000006
values: ConfigureWindowAux { x: Some(100), y: Some(100), width: None, height: None, border_width: None, sibling: None, stack_mode: None }
```

What could be the problem?

Note: I also tried resizing the window. Nothing happened. And if I run this `xdotool windowmove 0x4000006 100 100` in the terminal, the terminal **does move**.

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=930d53ef133dc59c727ed5bc64f2adad)

Comment: X11 is asynchronous. After your Configure request, you have to loop on XNextEvent or something like this in order to make the server consume your request. Maybe XFlush is enough.

Comment: @prog-fh Hey, thanks. I think that's the correct answer. Could you post an answer with a short explanation and short example?

Comment: It's done, thanks for your invitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

X11 is asynchronous.

After sending a request, we have to flush the command stream in order to make sure the server considers it.

When using a traditional event loop (with `XNextEvent()`, `XPending()`...) the flush is implicit.
Here we have to flush explicitly, since there is no such loop; the program exits right after the request is sent.

```rust
    conn.configure_window(win, &values)?;
    conn.flush()?;
```

Note that on my platform, I had to change the window id to the parent (my window manager is probably different from yours).

Comment: Thanks again for the answer. For some reason, `conn.flush()` isn't enough. I either need a `loop` or `sleep`.

Answer (score 0):

Some extension on @prog-fh's good answer and a reply to the comment to it:

> Thanks again for the answer. For some reason, conn.flush() isn't enough

When you just `flush()` and then immediately close the X11 connection (by dropping it), there is a race: The X11 server sees both "the client closed its connection" and "there is some data left to read". And apparently the X11 server prefers to handle the connection close and discards the remaining data.

Thus, you need to make sure the server actually received the data. For this, a [helper function `sync()` exists](https://docs.rs/x11rb/latest/x11rb/wrapper/trait.ConnectionExt.html#method.sync). All it does is to send a `GetInputFocus` request and wait for its answer. The X11 protocol guarantees that the server handles requests in-order, thus any request generated before the `GetInputFocus` request must already have been handled before.